# how can send a verification code on my app for that the user complete your registration in the app?

Tags: java, android, user-registration

I am making a chat application and I want that a verification code will sent to the phone number that you enter the user and thus register on my app but I do not know how start

Comment: do you have any means of sending text messages through your server?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, what have you tried, and what exactly will the end result be?

Comment: I pretend that when the user enter the verification code, the user  register on the server and he have the access  to the chat app. nafas I do know not how to implement sending messages on my server

Comment: i need as said Jim send SMS messages by server for have access to the chat app like a whatsapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you state "sent to the phone number" then it sounds like you are not sending a WiFi or mobile data message (like using Google Cloud Messaging) but rather using SMS.

To send SMS messages by server you need a gateway:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

You can buy those services - do a search for "sms gaateway messaging" and you'll find plenty.